# Any way to get the path parameters in httpservlet request

Tags: rest, servlets, jersey, path-parameter

I have rest service implemented.

I am trying to get the path parameters of the the request in filter.

My request is

**`/api/test/{id1}/{status}`**

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
         //Way to get the path parameters id1 and status


     }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no other way to do it in a ServletFilter other than trying to parse the URI yourself, but you can access the path parameters if you decide to use a JAX-RS request filter:

```
@Provider
public class PathParamterFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
     public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters = request.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();
        pathParameters.get("status");
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

You can autowire HttpServletRequest in your filter and use it to get information.

```
@Autowire
HttpServletRequest httpRequest


httpRequest.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE)  

will give you map of path params.
```

Example:

If your request is like url/{requestId} then above map will return

```
0 = {LinkedHashMap$Entry@12596} "requestId" -> "a5185067-612a-422e-bac6-1f3d3fd20809"
 key = "requestId"
 value = "a5185067-612a-422e-bac6-1f3d3fd20809"
```

Comment: but care this need some filters to run before it can be used!

Comment: Any example of that?

Comment: is this only with Spring MVC?

Comment: Little code example:

Map<String, String> pathAttributes = (Map)request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
pathAttributes.get("id")

Answer (score 2):

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
    if (pathInfo != null) {
        String[] parts = pathInfo.split("/");
        int indexOfName = Arrays.asList(parts).indexOf("test");
        if (indexOfName != -1) {
            Optional<String> testId1 = Optional.of(parts[indexOfName + 1]);
            Optional<String> status= Optional.of(parts[indexOfName + 2]);
        }

    }
```

Your Servlet Mapping should be till /api/*
eg. `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/api/*"})`

Comment: this is the most native way !