# How to get the URI parameter in a HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, uri, interceptor

I am using a javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest to implement a web application.

I have problem how to get the URI parameter of a request?

Complete URL is: /xyz/{value}/{name}/{status}

How to get the value, name and status from URL using HttpServletRequest ?

Comment: If you are using Spring, much easier to use  `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to get the path parameters in httpservlet request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199830/any-way-to-get-the-path-parameters-in-httpservlet-request)